# OrientDB Reverse Proxy with Apache

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, orientdb

I am using OrientDB to serve as a RESTful way to do GET and POST data back and forth to my AJAX application. I have now setup Apache to serve out the AJAX application and do reverse proxy to the OrientDB RESTful calls to get around cross domain restrictions. For the most part things are happy but for part of my application I use jsTree (http://www.jstree.com/) to dynamically load tree nodes and for some unknown reason it is working on every other AJAX load of child nodes.

In the AJAX application http network trace I get "204 No Content" and in the Apache logs I see:

```
APR does not understand this error code: proxy: pass request body failed
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.  : proxy: error reading status line from remote server
```

I have tried setting timeouts and keep alive settings but nothing has helped as of yet. I am imagining that there is some magic setting that will get this to work like it was but I have not found that as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

The apache error:

> proxy: error reading status line from remote server

means that the origin server (OrientDB in your case) is killing the established TCP connection with the client (apache as reverse proxy) before apache can send the request body to OrientDB.

It could happen when the client (the browser) begins a HTTP request to apache but it's slow sending the request. Apache opens a connection to OrientDB, but orientdb closes the connection due to inactivity timeout. At this point, an error is raised and the connection with the broser returns with no luck.

Try to raise the HTTP timeout in OrientDB.